# spring:autowire needs webapplication?

Tags: java, spring

I am using autowire like the following:

```
 @Autowired
    @Required
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

But it error out like

```
2014-12-02 06:37:04 DEBUG QuartzSchedulerThread:276 - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
2014-12-02 06:37:04 DEBUG JobRunShell:201 - Calling execute on job ETLConnectorJobGroup_ID16.ETLConnectorJob_ID16
2014-12-02 06:37:04 DEBUG SpringBeanAutowiringSupport:89 - Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of ConnectorScheduler: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
```

Does `Autowired` need spring MVC since it complain `WebApplicationContext` is not available

update:
I wrongly used `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` from MVC, after remove it the error is gone.

Comment: Why did you post _that_ `@Autowired` target? What does `ConnectorScheduler` contain? Is there anything else in the logs?

Comment: No, @Autowired does not need MVC. Put more code, especially how ConnectorScheduler is constructed